# What $a$ makes the sequence $X_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+a}$ strictly decreasing st $a$ is a positive real number?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was playing with geogebra and notice that the sequence $X_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+a}$ is strictly increasing if $a=0$ or for generality $f(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+a}$ such that $x$ is positive real number

But when I increase $a$ to be less than some number less than $0.5$
the function is not strictly increasing anymore.

[image]

But when $a$ is around $0.5$ the function seem to be strictly decreasing and I will denote that number when $a$ reaches the function become strictly decreasing by $C$.
[image]

So what exactly is $C$ that if $a>C$ then the function is strictly decreasing and what happens if $a=C$?

Answer (score 4):

If you differentiate with respect to $x$, you will find that the monotonicity will depend on the sign of
$$
\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right) - \frac{{x + a}}{{x(x + 1)}}.
$$
The change occurs when this expression is $0$, i.e., when
$$
a =a(x) = x(x + 1)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right) - x.
$$
Hence, your critical $a$ is not constant, it depends on $x$. Expanding for $x\ge 1$, gives
$$
a(x) = \frac{1}{1\cdot 2} - \frac{1}{{2\cdot 3}}\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{{3\cdot 4 }}\frac{1}{x^2} -\frac{1}{4\cdot 5}\frac{1}{x^3}+  \frac{1}{5\cdot 6}\frac{1}{x^4}-\ldots \,.
$$
Hence for large positive $x$, the change occurs around $a=\frac{1}{2}$.

Another interesting quantity is $\tilde a(x)$ for which
$$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right)^{x + \tilde a(x)}  = {\rm e}.
$$
Explicitly,
$$
\tilde a(x) = \frac{1}{{\log (1 + 1/x)}} - x.
$$
Expanding for $x\ge 1$, gives
$$
\tilde a(x) = x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{b_n }}{{x^n }}}  = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{{12}}\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{{24}}\frac{1}{{x^2 }} - \frac{{19}}{{720}}\frac{1}{{x^3 }} + \frac{3}{{160}}\frac{1}{{x^4 }} -  \ldots ,
$$
where the $b_n$ denote the [Bernoulli numbers of the second kind](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.16.i).

Comment: this is strange because when I graph the function $ f(x)=
\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right) - \frac{{x + a}}{{x(x + 1)}}.
$ and make $a$ move between 0 and 1 it seems that the function is always decreasing so $a$ is constant

Comment: @pie You have to look at the sign of that function, and not whether it is decreasing or not.

Comment: I meant that the original function is decreasing and the other function is negative 
when I command the zero of the function to geogebra it approach infinity as a approach 0.5 , and between 0.5 and 1 there is no positive real root so the sign of the second function can't change it stays always negative

Comment: I took $a=1/4$ and found a zero at $x=0.24297434\ldots$.

Comment: when a=0.49, x=16.167
when a=0.499 , x=166.167
when a=0.4999 , x=1666.17
when a=0.49999, x=16666.2
when a=0.499999 , x=166666

Comment: it seems like adding 9s make the root put another 6 on the right which is more strange
but when a be any number higher than 0.5 makes x = negative number

Comment: It is clear from the expansion of $a(x)$ that as itt apporaches $1/2$, $x$ must tend to infinity. If $a>1/2$, your original function will be decreasing. If $a<1/2$ then it will *eventually* be increasing.